# How to make changes to a configmap take effect immediately without restart the pod?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

Imagining a MySQL application is using a configmap to store it's my.cnf file. After a modification to that my.cnf file the changes take about **a minute** to take effect (appearing inside the MySQL container), it's time-consuming. Is there a way to speed it up?

I tried pod annotation like `sync-config-map-time":"20220210-010101`, and update the annotation after a configmap modification, but this would make the application pod restarts all the time. Is there any better solution to tackle this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately this feature will be available in a future. You can check a progress on [GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22368). At this moment I can recommend you [Reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader). Let me know if this is helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer as a community wiki, feel free to edit and expand.

---

Unfortunately this feature will be available in a future. You can check a progress on [GitHub](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22368)

At this moment I can recommend you [Reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader#-reloader).

> We would like to watch if some change happens in `ConfigMap` and/or `Secret`; then perform a rolling upgrade on relevant `DeploymentConfig`, `Deployment`, `Daemonset`, `Statefulset` and `Rollout`

> Reloader can watch changes in `ConfigMap` and `Secret` and do rolling upgrades on Pods with their associated `DeploymentConfigs`, `Deployments`, `Daemonsets`  `Statefulsets` and `Rollouts`.